# Approach to map the clustering output with existing data indexes

Tags: data-mining, mahout

I am newbie to Mahout and working on a data mining clustering use case using K-Means. I need a help to understand how to map the original data with the clustered output to gain more insight. Let say

After performing data preparation we have a summarized data set having following attributes

```
Key1,Key2,Dimension1,Dimension2,Measure1,Measure2,Measure3
```

Now I have executed clustering algorithm on following attributes

```
Measure1,Measure2,Measure3
```

Output of the clustering would be Cluster Id with its data(Measure1,Measure2,Measure3).

**Question:
How can I perform clustering on specific attributes in dataset, where the clustered output must contain all attributes.**

Request to help me with right approach.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What is your confusion?

Comment: @rrenaud I have edited my post and tried to frame the question correctly.

Comment: This is IMHO a question on the **usage of mahout**, not a programming question. As such, I would suggest to ask it in the Mahout user mailing list, not in a programming community like SO.

Comment: Thanks @Anony...I will do so....as this is common data mining problem hence I thought to take help from SME in SO.